# ImageRootPIDL - get the value

Tags: c#

is there a way to decode information that is contain in *C:\Users\$username$\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\slideshow.ini*, 
to string than contains the path to wallpapers slideshow in c# or similar .net language?

Comment: Have you tried a Google search for "c# read ini file"?

Comment: @RenniePet I am guessing the problem is decoding the encoded string inside that file, not reading the data from the file.

Comment: yes, i don't know how to encode that PIDL data

Comment: Are you looking to read/write the data or only read it?  I would recommend using the [IDesktopWallpaper.GetSlideshow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to read the data.